# How to get suite name from Robot Frame Work

Tags: robotframework

I have used `${SUITE NAME}` tag. It is giving the `Suite` name along with the path as
`"Robotframework.TestSuites.foldername.testsuitename"`. I need suite name only. How can I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in-line as well.

```
${SUITE NAME.rsplit('.')[0]}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
${the name}=    Set Variable    ${SUITE NAME}

# split the output on every . character
${the name}=    Split String    ${the name}     separator=.

# get the last member of the split
${the name}=    Set Variable    @{the name}[-1]

Log To Console      ${the name}    # prints testsuitename in your example
```

P.S. It'll get nasty if you use dots in your suite names.

Comment: In the 3rd step `@{the name}[-1]` should be `@{the name[-1]}`

Comment: @OrsuSuni that is not quite so. Check [Accessing individual list items](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables), the format of accessing list members is like I've written. The `@` operand does list expansion, and with the slice you're selecting the last element. The call `{the name[-1]}` is a part of the [Extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax), and it would work if the var is called with `$`, but will fail with the `@` as you proposed, as ...

Comment: ... the member is not a list-like object (it's a string), thus cannot be expanded. Feel free to check for yourself, that won't work :)

Comment: You are right !! Thanks for your information and sorry for my misconception :)

Comment: No problem, and nothing to excuse about; the purpose of my comment was to explain what's happening, a bit more knowledge share - what SO IMHO is about.